# How to solve the given PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the given PDE:
$$p_t=-(wp_y+zp_x)+B(p_{yy}+p_{xx})$$
where $p(x,y,t)$ and $B,w,z$ are constants
I know how to solve the equation given by
$$p_t=B(p_{yy}+p_{xx})$$
**as the steps are analogus to heat equation solution**. But cannot figure out the solution and the necessary steps for solving 
$$p_t=-(wp_y+zp_x)+B(p_{yy}+p_{xx})$$
for certain boundary conditions, preferably using Fourier series? Can somebody provide me a brief outline for the general solution?

Comment: the method of eigenfunction expansion..

Comment: @Shogun  can you please provide me a little bit of more details in the answer?

Comment: I would suggest making the transform $p(x,y,t) \to q(x+\alpha t,y+\beta t,t) = q(\hat{x}, \hat{y}, t)$. Computing derivatives gives \begin{align} p_{t} &\to \alpha q_\hat{x} + \beta q_\hat{y} + q_{t} \\ p_{x} &\to q_\hat{x} \implies p_{xx} \to q_{\hat{x} \hat{x}} \\ p_{y} &\to q_{\hat{x}} \implies p_{yy} \to q_{\hat{y} \hat{y}} \end{align} and inserting in the PDE gives the heat equation in $q$ $$q_{t} = B(q_{\hat{x} \hat{x}} + q_{\hat{y} \hat{y}})$$ where $\alpha = -z, \beta = -w$. Now you just need to change your datum accordingly.

Comment: @Mattos Just one doubt for the solution of heat equation we can assume $p(x,y,t)=p_1(x)p_2(y)p_3(t)$, can we have the same assumption for $q(\hat{x},\hat{y},t)$. I am asking because here $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ are not independent of eachother and $t$.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the variables $\hat{x}, \hat{y}$ represent. You are trying to solve the _new_ PDE, not the old one, and your new PDE is entirely in terms of $\hat{x}, \hat{y}$. So you need to make your ansatz in terms of these new variables. So you should look for a separable solution of the form $q(\hat{x},\hat{y},t) = q_{1}(\hat{x})q_{2}(\hat{y})q_{3}(t)$.

Comment: Just so you know, the original PDE is separable as is.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks! It will be really helpful if you can provide your hints and help in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

After Laplace transforming, consider the PDE

$$
s p(x,s)-p(x,0) = \partial_x(ap(x,s)+b\partial_x p(x,s))
$$

now assuming $p(x,0) = 0$ for simplicity, the resolution follows much the way an ODE

$$
p(x,s) = c_1(s) e^{\frac{1}{2} x \left(-\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4 b s}}{b}-\frac{a}{b}\right)}+c_2(s) e^{\frac{1}{2} x \left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4 b
   s}}{b}-\frac{a}{b}\right)}
$$

now knowing the boundary conditions for $x$ we can determine $c_1(s), c_2(s)$ and after that we obtain the Laplace inversion: directly or with the help of residue theory.

NOTE

Considering $p(x,y,t) = X(x)Y(y)T(t)$ with the PDE

$$
p_t = b(p_{xx}+p_{yy})
$$

we have

$$
\frac{\dot T}{T} = b\left(\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}\right) = \lambda
$$

and also

$$
\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y} = \frac{\lambda}{b}\Rightarrow \frac{X''}{X} = \frac{\lambda}{b}-\frac{Y''}{Y} = \mu
$$

so we have

$$
\dot T = \lambda T\\
X'' = \mu X\\
Y'' = \left(\frac{\lambda}{b}-\mu\right)Y
$$

Comment: Sorry! I am not an expert in PDEs but I want to know can it be solved using separation of variables $p(x,y,t)=p(x)p(y)p(t)$ and then using Fourier series. I am comfortable using them.

Comment: @Userhanu Please. See attached note.

Comment: I am thankful for your detailed note. However, I know how to apply separation of variables for $p_t=B(p_{xx}+p_{yy})$ I just want to know how to do the same when we have $p_t=-(wp_y+zp_x)+B(p_{xx}+p_{yy})$. Basically, How should I connect your note to the answer that you have provided for my originally posed problem.

Comment: $$\frac{\dot T}{T} = b\frac{X''}{X}-w\frac{X'}{X}+b\frac{Y''}{Y}-z\frac{Y'}{Y} = \lambda$$
$$
b\frac{X''}{X}-w\frac{X'}{X} = \lambda -b\frac{Y''}{Y}+z\frac{Y'}{Y}=\mu
$$
so we have $\dot T = \lambda T$, $b X''-wX'=\mu X$ etc.